# detecting substrings in column based on a vector of patterns

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a df with a particular column with a rough list of company names to identify the row (the data is untidy -> ex. Company John S Doe = Company JohnSDoe = Companyjohnsdoe = ...). I also have a list of certain companies I want identified and written out more neatly in another column. For example:

```
keywords <- c(company1,company2,company3,...)

DF2 <- DF1 %>%
         mutate(stripped = tolower(str_replace_all(clmpye_name_tx, fixed(" "), "")),
                company_name_clean= case_when(grepl("company1",stripped, fixed = T) ~ "Company1",
                                              grepl("company2",stripped, fixed = T) ~ "Company2",
                                              grepl("company3",stripped, fixed = T) ~ "Company3",....)) %>% ....
```

Now as you can see above I can do this manually for each entry in the vector, however in future queries with this data, in the case I add keywords to this list, the goal would be to streamline this process without going back and adding more cases to the case_when.

Are there any alternatives that would accomplish this?

---

Sample Data:

```
keywords <- c("johnscompany","daveabc")
```

| unclean_names | stripped | clean_names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JohnscompaNy | johnscompany | Johnscompany |
| Johns company | johnscompany | Johnscompany |
| Dave ABC | daveabc | Daveabc |
| daveabc | daveabc | Daveabc |

```
df <- structure(list(unclean_names = c("JohnscompaNy", "Johns company", 
"Dave ABC", "daveabc"), stripped = c("johnscompany", "johnscompany", 
"daveabc", "daveabc"), clean_names = c("Johnscompany", "Johnscompany", 
"Daveabc", "Daveabc")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

and so on. Also note not all companies are to be mapped only the ones in the initialized vector.

What I had done (which I forgot to include in the code, it has since been updated), is starting by stripping the unclean_name column and identifying it with the keywords. The manual way works perfectly fine but I was wondering if there is a way to generalize this for any number of keywords if some are added in the future.

Comment: (1) Are you able to make this reproducible? `dput(head(DF1,20))` and `keywords` would be useful. (2) *"collapsed combinations of identifiers"* sounds unnecessary, why collapse them instead of keeping them as individual columns?

Comment: @r2evans I have since updated the question. I also made the mistake of wrongly saying there was a key, it is not a key but the data is saved untidely and the goal of this column is to organize it. thx!

Comment: @r2evans I made it *actually* reproducible

Comment: @A03 I still don't think the example is very good. Are all of the company names in keyword *actually* all lowercase with spaces removed? Do you *really* want the names to be all one word?

Comment: if that is the case, `df |> mutate(company_name = str_to_title(str_remove_all(unclean_names, " ")), .keep = "none")` works